Fixed point iteration derivative derivations do not match...
Setup
Suppose I have a function $g(x,s)$ with fixed parameter $s$ and seek the minimum over $x$.
One can propose an iterative scheme, e.g. gradient descent, where, $x_{i+1} = h(x_i,s) = x_i - \alpha \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}|_i $
At the minimum, which exists, this yields a fixed point, $x^* = h(x^*, s) = x^* - \alpha \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}|_*$
Use this to determine the sensitivity of this minimum to parameter $s$ as follows:
$$\frac{dx^*}{ds} = \frac{d h}{d s} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x^*}\frac{d x^*}{d s} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial s } =  \left ( 1 - \alpha \left . \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial x} \right |_{x^*} \right ) \frac{d x^*}{ds} - \alpha \left . \frac{\partial g}{\partial x \partial s} \right |_{x^*} $$
$$ \implies \quad \frac{d x^*}{d s} = \left . \frac{-\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial s} }{ \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial x} } \right |_{x^*}$$
This works fine and I have been happily applying the formula to various problems.
Extension
Suppose now I have a function $r(x, s)$ which is a root finding problem, varying $x$, for which there does exist a root. If I square $r$ then my root finding problem becomes a minimisation problem where the minimum achieved will equal zero. In this case,
$$ g(x,s) = r^2(x, s), \quad \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial s} = 2 (r \frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x \partial s} + \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial s}), \quad \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x \partial x} = 2 (r \frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x \partial x} + \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} ) $$
$$ \implies \quad \frac{d x^*}{d s} = \left . \frac{- ( r \frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x \partial s} + \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial s})}{ r \frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x \partial x} + \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} } \right |_{x^*}$$
Question
If I try to derive the same equation using the same logic from a Newton root solving algorithm I do not obtain the same sensitivity. Either the logic is incorrect or, more likely I have made a mistake,
Propose the Newton iterative scheme, $x_{i+1} = x_i - \frac{r(x_i, s)}{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}|_i} $
At the root this yields $x^* = h(x^*, s) = x^* - \frac{r(x^*, s)}{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}|_*} $
Use this to determine the sensitivity of this root to parameter $s$ as follows:
$$\frac{dx^*}{ds} = \frac{d h}{d s} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x^*}\frac{d x^*}{d s} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial s } =  \left (  \frac{r(x^*, s)}{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}|_*  \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}|_*} \frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x \partial x}|_* \right ) \frac{d x^*}{ds} +  \frac{r(x^*, s)}{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}|_*  \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}|_*} \frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x \partial s}|_* - \frac{ \frac{\partial r}{\partial s}|_*}{\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}|_*} $$
$$ \implies \quad \frac{d x^*}{d s} = \left . \frac{- ( r \frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x \partial s} - \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial s})}{ r \frac{\partial^2 r}{\partial x \partial x} - \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} } \right |_{x^*}$$
which differs from the former in the plus/minus signs. Why?
